# error C2146 and C4430

Tags: windows

First: sorry my bad English =((

Sencond:

here's my code in "Global.h":

```
#pragma once
class GlobalVariable
{
public:
    GlobalVariable(void);
    ~GlobalVariable(void);

    //------------------------------------------------
public:
    double pixelWidth;      //  do rong cua 1 pixel tren Viewport
    double pixelHeigh;      //  do cao cua 1 pixel tren Viewport

public:
    Point   oldPoint,   tempPoint;
    Circle  oldCir,     tempCir;
    DaGiac  oldDaGiac,  tempDaGiac;
    Color   oldObjColor,tempObjColor, OxyColor;

};

class Point
{
public:
    Point(void);
    ~Point(void);

    double  x,y;            // toạ độ (x,y)
};

class Color
{
public:
    Color(void);
    ~Color(void);

    double R,G,B;           // màu (R,G,B)
};

class DaGiac
{
public:
    DaGiac(void);
    ~DaGiac(void);

    int numOfPeak;  //so' dinh?
    Point peakArr[10];  //  ve da giac canh so dinh toi da la 10
};

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(void);
    ~Circle(void);

    Point centre;
    double radius;
```

};

---

and I have some eror :(

```
------ Build started: Project: GAS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
GlobalVariable.cpp
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(15) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'oldPoint'
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(15) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(15) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(15) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(16) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'oldCir'
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(16) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(16) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(16) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(17) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'oldDaGiac'
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(17) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(17) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(17) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(18) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'oldObjColor'
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(18) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(18) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(18) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
e:\documents\bin\gas_project\globalvariable.h(18) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Build log was saved at "file://e:\Documents\BIN\GAS_Project\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
GAS - 17 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

But after I delete the GlobalVariable   class!  Only class  Point, Color, DaGiac, Circle  exist!   It has no eror!
Tell me why?   And how to corect that error ?  Please =((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't "see" the other classes, because they're defined *after* the `GlobalVariable` class. Move the whole `GlobalVariable` class to the bottom of the file so that all of the classes it depends on will be defined when it needs them.